# azure devops release pipeline refresh variable group value to latest value

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I would like that, during a release pipeline, if I update the value of a variable in a variable group the pipeline release uses the last value.
The scenario is similar to the one I am going to show.
I have a release pipeline with two Stages. Suppose "**StageA**" and "**StageB**".
The execution of "**StageB**" is after "**StageA**" and before the execution of "**StageB**" I have a manual approval. (**StageA** is automatic after release creation)

Pipeline stages

[image: 1]

In the Pipeline I have linked a variable group **VG-StageB** with scope **StageB**
The variable groups contain a variable called "*TestVariable*".
Lets suppose that "*TestVariable*" contains the value "**First value**".
Lets suppose that the "**StageB**" contains only one task that "echoes" TestVariable:
echo $(*TestVariable*)

If I follow this steps:

1. **Create Release** from the pipeline
   this create "Release 1". StageA automatically executed and then the release stops waiting for an approval before StageB
2. **Change the value of *TestVariable*** in VG-StageB to "**Second value**"
3. Approve "**StageB**".
   What happens is that the echo of *TestVariable* shows "*First value*".

The question is:
Is there a way that the result of the echo is "***Second value***"?

Comment: Have you tried the following steps to check if it meet your requirements?

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, you could try to add a PowerShell task to update this variable by using the [REAT API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1).

1. Go to the Agent job to check the 'Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token'
2. Add a PowerShell task in "StageA" of the release pipeline.
3. Use the following script.

```js
$VariableGroupId = "{variableGroupId}"
$NewValue = "Second value"
$VariableName = "TestVariable"
Write-Host "NewValue : $NewValue"
$url =
"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/$($VariableGroupId)?api-version=7.1-preview.2"
Write-Host "URL: $url"
$authHeader = @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}
$definition = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $authHeader
Write-Host "Pipeline = $($definition | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
$definition.variables.$VariableName.Value = "$($NewValue)"
$definitionJson = $definition | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 -Compress
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Uri $url -Headers $authHeader -ContentType "application/json" -Body ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($definitionJson)) | Out-Null
```

Note: Make sure the "Project Collection Build service" with the administrator permission in the variable group.

[image: Build service]

Comment: Thank tou. The powershell code is ok, but I would prefer a solution as a flag in variable group.